# pygame rotation around center point

Tags: rotation, pygame, center

I've read several other posts about rotating an image around the center point, but I've yet to figure it out. I even copy pasted one of the solutions posted on another SO question and it didn't work.

This is my code

```
  def rotate(self, angle):
    self.old_center = self.surface.get_rect().center
    self.surface = pygame.transform.rotate(self.surface, angle)
    self.surface.get_rect(center = self.old_center)
```

it's inside a class which contains the surface.

When I call this method the image rotates but also translates, and gets distorted.

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning the new rect, you should do something like:

```
self.rect = self.surface.get_rect(center = self.old_center)
```

And you should always keep the original surface and rotate from the original, that way distortion doesn't accumulate when rotating multiple times.

**Update**

If you don't want to keep track of the `rect` object, you can do it every time you blit. If you keep the `center` coordinates.

Example:

```
rect = object.surface.get_rect()
rect.center = object.center
display.blit(object.surface, rect.topleft)
```

Comment: I was under the impression that "self.surface = pygame.transform.rotate(self.surface, angle)" implicitly assigned a new rotated rect since rect is a property of the surface.

My class doesn't contain a rect property, I use surface.get_rect() everytime.